Does HoloLens 2 have Built-in Point Clouds?
Our group has some uncertainty about what point cloud functionality the HoloLens 2 has available to developers, and how best to obtain point clouds from it.
We have been testing with HoloLens2's Research Mode, and it appears to me, based off of the StreamRecorder sample, that point clouds need to be generated from the depth camera data and IMU data.
However, our team is curious if there is point cloud data already generated somewhere on the device that can be accessed, avoiding the need to generate our own.
There is also confusion in the team about whether the Depth Camera frames in pCameraReader->m_pSensorFrame (RMCameraReader.cpp) are actually raw feed direct from the Depth Camera, or if the frames have undergone processing before that point, or if they might even be generated from a point cloud source or something as such.

Not aware of any internally created point clouds
